# Template interpolation in function argument results in TS2554:Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Following the Getting Started guide for Testcafe at http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/ I'm having trouble modifying the sample test script.

Typescript version: 2.7.2 Node version: 8.7.0 Webstorm version: 2017.2.6

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://some-website.com`;

test('Test', async t => {

})
```

This compiles and runs fine.  I have read that Typescript supports string templating, and the example test already uses backticks to surround its strings, so I tried factoring out a portion of the URL:

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

let domain = 'some-website.com';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://${domain}`;

test('Test', async t => {

})
```

This results in the error "TS2554:Expected 1 arguments, but got 2" and webstorm highlights the two lines of code beginning at `fixture(`.

Trying to completely replace the argument to `.page` with a variable results in a different compilation error.

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

let domain:string = 'premierrange-local.com';
let str:string = `http://${domain}`;

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page str;

test('Test', async t => {

})
```

"TS1005:';' expected." on the `str` variable usage.

However, putting `str` in brackets solves the compile error:

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

let domain:string = 'premierrange-local.com';
let str:string = `http://${domain}`;

fixture(`Getting Started`)
    .page(str);

test('Test', async t => {

})
```

This compiles and runs fine.  So it seems the brackets around `page`'s arguments are required if a variable is being passed, but not if a string literal is?  But my first attempt simply introduced a variable interpolation and it was treated as a compile error.

The definition for `page()` looks like this (from `node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts`):

```
page(url: string  | TemplateStringsArray): this;
```

Can someone explain why Typescript considers my first modifications illegal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tagged templates usually have [two parameters](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html), the first parameter will contain the sting literals, and the second parameter will be a spread parameter and will contain the replacement values.

```
function tagged(url: TemplateStringsArray, ...values:any[]){
    return "url";
}

let d = tagged `ss ${0}`; // conceptually equivalent to tagged(["value ", " (s)"], 0);
```

While this is the usual way, we can play around with the definition, since tagged templates are equivalent to function calls, we can play around with the parameters to the tagged template, and the typescript compiler will check their compatibility

```
function tagged(url: TemplateStringsArray, ...values:number[]){
    return "url";
}
let v1 = 0;
let v2 = ''
let d = tagged `value ${v1} ${v2}(s)`; // error, replacement values must be numbers and v2 is a string
```

In the case of the `testcafe` function, there is only one parameter , the first one, so there is no parameter for the replacement values, therefore even though we can use the tagged template syntax to call `page` there is no parameter to accept the replacement values and thus any replacement values will generate an error. I thing the designers of `testcafe` just wanted to use the tagged syntax, but did not necessarily what to performance any replacements in the string.

You can work around this limitation by calling `page` using a regular function call to `page`:

```
let site = 'some-website'
fixture `Getting Started`
    .page (`http://${site}.com`);
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the "tagged template" feature of Typescript described before.  It looks like the Testcafe usage of it is pointless, e.g. their docs at http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#specifying-the-start-webpage show the normal function invocation of `page()` and the tagged template invocation as being equivocal, yet their template string has no parameters in it.  Is their example needlessly complicated or is there a good reason they used a string template?

Comment: @Neek i don't know their reasoning.. it looks pointless from functional point of view, I think they were going for a 'directive' look to these calls.. but I can't really say for sure.